# Eliminar datos en DATATABLE en Flet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter

Hola estoy haciendo un CRUD en Flet con Python hasta ahora  mi CRUD me funciona bien con agregar, ahora quiero hacer para eliminar los datos del DataTable pero usando un **IconButton** que al momento de presionar el IconButton me elimine el dato del DataTable pero me sale este mensaje: **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

La imagen del CRUD que estoy haciendo de modo de practica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero su pronta ayuda, gracias.
Aqui les dejo el codigo:

import flet as ft
from flet import *

def main(page: ft.Page):

```
codpro = TextField(label="CÓDIGO PRODUCTO")
nompro = TextField(label="NOMBRE PRODUCTO")

#combo de categoria
ddcate = ft.Dropdown(label="CATEGORIA",
    width=150,
    options=[
        ft.dropdown.Option("dulce"),
        ft.dropdown.Option("salado"),
    ],
)

#combo de peso
ddpeso = ft.Dropdown(label="PESO",
    width=100,
    options=[
        ft.dropdown.Option("KG"),
        ft.dropdown.Option("G"),
    ],
)


tablaproducto = DataTable(
              #CABECERA DE LAS CALUMNAS  
              columns=[
                  DataColumn(Text("CÓDIGO")),
                  DataColumn(Text("PRODUCTO")),
                  DataColumn(Text("CATEGORÍA")),
                  DataColumn(Text("PESO")),
                  DataColumn(Text("ACCIONES")),
              ],
              #FILAS  
              rows=[]          
)

#FUNCION ELIMINAR
def eliminar(e):
    del tablaproducto.rows[codpro.value]
    
    #MENSAJE con Barra inferior
    page.snack_bar = SnackBar(
        Text("SE ELIMINO DATO", size = 30),
        bgcolor = "red"
        
    )
    page.snack_bar.open = True
    #FIN DEL MENSAJE inferior

    page.update()



#FUNCION para AGREGAR     
def agregar(e):
    tablaproducto.rows.append(
        DataRow(
            cells=[
                DataCell(Text(codpro.value)),
                DataCell(Text(nompro.value)),
                DataCell(Text(ddcate.value)),
                DataCell(Text(ddpeso.value)),
                DataCell(
                    Row([
                    IconButton("delete", 
                               icon_color ="red",
                               on_click = eliminar),
                    ])
                    ),
            ]
        )
    )
    #MENSAJE con Barra inferior
    page.snack_bar = SnackBar(
        Text("DATO INGRESADO CORRECTAMENTE", size = 30),
        bgcolor = "green"
    )
    page.snack_bar.open = True
    #FIN DEL MENSAJE

    page.update()

   
#Boton AGREGAR
BtnAgregar = ElevatedButton(
    text="Agregar", 
    bgcolor="blue",
    color="white",
    on_click=agregar
    )


page.add(
    Column([
        Text("PRODUCTOS",size=30,weight="bold"),
        codpro, nompro,ddcate, ddpeso,
        Row([BtnAgregar]),
        tablaproducto

        ])

    )
```

ft.app(target=main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar el problema con esta linea de codigo

```
def eliminar(e):
        tablaproducto.rows.remove(tablaproducto.rows[0])

        #MENSAJE con Barra inferior
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(
            Text("SE ELIMINO DATO", size = 30),
            bgcolor = "red"            
        )
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        #FIN DEL MENSAJE inferior
 
        page.update()
```

Gracias